# How access size information of a image via code

Tags: image, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm using Delphi 10.1 Berlin and I need to create an image and set his Canvas size equals to be equal to the bitmap size. To be more specific I want to access this properties: [image]

Where say: "Sized by Image". But I can't figure out how can I acces this, help please! :-D

EDIT: This is the code that I'm using, if you guys need to understand better what I'm trying to achieve:

```
imgProdutoZoom := TImage.Create(rtFundoArredondadoZoom);
imgProdutoZoom.Parent := rtFundoArredondadoZoom;
imgProdutoZoom.Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
imgProdutoZoom.Bitmap.Assign(imgProduto.Bitmap);
imgProdutoZoom.WrapMode := TImageWrapMode.Fit;
imgProdutoZoom.Name := 'imgZoom'+ IntToStr(i);
```

I found this code: `imgProdutoZoom.MultiResBitmap.SizeKind.Source;`
But the console give me an error: '[dcc32 Error] MainFrm.pas(628): E2018 Record, object or class type required'

Comment: I'm not sure if I get the question right. But the original's resolution shouldn't be imgProducto.Bitmap.Height and imgProducto.Bitmap.Width ?. Is that what you are looking for ?.

Comment: I just want to have access to this property "Seize by image". I don't want the Height and Width of my Image

Comment: I can be wrong, but I don't think that's a property. If you want to set the size of your TImage exactly as the original source, then just do : imgProdutoZoom.Height := imgProduto.Bitmap.Height;  and  imgProductoZoom.Width := imgProduto.Bitmap.Width;

Comment: No, didn't worked. 'imgProdutoZoom.Height' is a single and 'imgProdutoZoom.Bitmap.Height' is a integer. Also my image just disapear...

Comment: I am extremely confused what you are trying to accomplish. Please read your entire question from our perspective, knowing nothing about what your project is, and ask yourself if you could answer it if you were us?

Comment: Also, it appears you're working with Firemonkey, yet are creating a simple Windows application. Is there any particular reason you're using Firemonkey instead of VCL?

Comment: @MarcGuillot Perhaps you're thinking of VCL, but the question is still very unclear.

Comment: Thanks Jerry, indeed I was thinking of VCL and I was also confused about the question. Diego, look a this blog, on Firemonkey you can use a Rectangle to get the same effect than a TImage, and it lets you set its size in Pixels (using the Height and Width of your original Bitmap). http://www.fmxexpress.com/trectangle-bitmap-instead-of-timage-for-delphi-xe5-firemonkey-on-android-and-ios/

Comment: I need to create an image and set his Canvas size equals to the bitmap size

Comment: If my post doesn't answer your question, please comment on it explaining what is wrong. Otherwise provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to eliminate any guessing.

Comment: I'll do this tonight. I think your post will help me, thanks man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not show what `rtFundoArredondadoZoom` is, but I assume it is a `TRectangle`.

When you set

```
imgProdutoZoom.Parent := rtFundoArredondadoZoom;
imgProdutoZoom.Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
```

you are telling to *fill up* the area of the parent (`rtFundoArredondadoZoom`). However, since `TImage.WrapMode` by default is `TImageWrapMode.Fit`, the image retains its aspect ratio and doesn't stretch to fill the parent.

Now, the limiting factor in your setup is the `rtFundoArredondadoZoom` rectangle, and specifically its height. To show the image in its full size, you need to set

```
rtFundoArredondadoZoom.Height := imgProdutoZoom.Bitmap.Height;
```

You may at times also want to set the width of the rectangle.

The following image shows an image in original size to the left, and te same image on a rectangle with smaller height using basically your code

[image]

Then after applying the height setting on the rectangle

[image]

Your code corrected accordingly would be:

```
imgProdutoZoom := TImage.Create(rtFundoArredondadoZoom);
imgProdutoZoom.Parent := rtFundoArredondadoZoom;
imgProdutoZoom.Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
imgProdutoZoom.Bitmap.Assign(imgProduto.Bitmap);
// imgProdutoZoom.WrapMode := TImageWrapMode.Fit; // not needed
rtFundoArredondadoZoom.Height := imgProdutoZoom.Bitmap.Height; // add this
imgProdutoZoom.Name := 'imgZoom'+ IntToStr(i);
```